# How to fetch specific key in result set in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a result set as :

{"access_token":"abc","refresh_token":"efg","token_type":"567","scope":78,"expires_in":78}

And i want to fetch only the vaule of access_token. How do i do it in python

Comment: What have you tried so far?  You have not shown any actual code.

Comment: Please refer to this guide on how to provide a [mre], and read about [ask]. Remember, we can't help you if we don't know what you've already tried.

Comment: You seem to have a dictionary structure, read how to extract value based on key from dict

Comment: is your issue that your result set is a string and you want to turn it into a dictionary to access the value of the given key or is the issue fundamentally how does one use a dictionary?  How is the value of the result set set?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the desired value like that

```
value0 = {"access_token":"abc","refresh_token":"efg","token_type":"567","scope":78,"expires_in":78}
access_token = value0.get("access_token")
print("Access Token value:", access_token)
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get' getting this error

Comment: That's not possible in the code given here - that error means that `value0` is `None`, but it's set to a value in the line immediately before. You must have copied or typed the code wrong.

Comment: @PratyasaMohanty provide a snippet of ur code

Comment: value0=print(response.text) Value0 is a resultset that is created dynamically

Comment: response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
value0=print(response.text)
access_token = value0.get("access_token")
print("Access Token value:", access_token)

Comment: After removing the print i still get the error

Comment: `value0 = response.json()`

Answer (score 0):

```
response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
response = response.json()
access_token = response.get("access_token")
print("Access Token value:", access_token)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: I suppose I should have added "You can get the desired value like that" like the other answer to which you did not ask to edit for an explanation.

Comment: Had the other answer popped up in the “Low Quality Answers” review queue on my watch, i certainly would have.

Comment: yeah because it is so difficult to see while looking at the same thread.

Comment: The review queues present each post independently. Regardless, instead of comparing yourself to another post, consider this an opportunity to improve your own.

Comment: so you have seen not only the vague OP but other responses, yet still no comment to any other than mine.